# Reflection Invoke Method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, abstract

I have the following C# Code. A Base class and classes that inherit from that base class.
I use this Baseclasses in an special List. This List also has the Member ReadListAsXmlAs.

```
public class ResultSetBase
{
   some Members
}

public class ResultSetBaseSweep : ResultSetBase
{
   some other Members
}

public class ResultList<T> where T : ResultSetBase
{
    public ResultList<T> ReadListAsXmlAs(params string[] path)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

In an other methode I want to create an dynamic object of the Type ResultList. I know of which class the ResultList is, only at runtime. (e.g. ResulstSetBaseSweep, or any other inherited from ResultSetBase).

I create an dynamic Object of this Type. the following way.

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("Class in String Format");
Type listtype = typeof(ResultSaver.ResultList<>).MakeGenericType(myType);

object resultlist = Activator.CreateInstance(listtype);
```

Now i need to call the Methode ReadListAsXmlAs. As it is of type object, the compiler complains when when i try to call

```
resultlist.ReadListAsXmlAs(...);
```

So I tried to call it over Reflections:

```
myType.InvokeMember("ReadListAsXmlAs", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, resultlist, new object[] { filenames.ToArray() });
```

Then I get the compiler error: ReadListAsXmlAs not found! How is it done right?

Comment: If you're using reflection, the final error would be a *runtime* error. Please quote that error in full.

Comment: If each subtype of `ResultSetBase` has a `ReadListAsXmlAs`, then make that a member of the base or define an interface and make `ReadListAsXmlAs` a member of it.

Comment: The runtime Error is: Method 'Tests.CAI.ATIC134_Family.NCK2983V2.SystemTests.ResultSetIQCal.ReadListAsXmlAs' not found.

Comment: I made an Interface 
  public interface IResultList<T> where T : ResultSetBase

Now I would be able, to call the ReadListAsXmlAs Methode. The Problem is, that i can not cast it to the generic Type of the ResultList<T> at runtime. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem:

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(LstBoxClass.SelectedItem.ToString());
Type listtype = typeof(ResultSaver.ResultList<>).MakeGenericType(myType);

object resultlist = Activator.CreateInstance(listtype);

MethodInfo method = listtype.GetMethod("ReadListAsXmlAs");
method.Invoke(resultlist, new Object[] {filenames.ToArray()});
```